# Using forward slash in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

i have setup(long ago) a project in the htdocs folder, i would like to have url like this:

```
http://localhost/_domain.com/profil/50bfbd859170a/home
```

right now urls are like this

```
http://localhost/_domain.com/profil-50bfbd859170a-home
```

i am unable to set forward slashes in urls on the htdoc folder (css and other files get unlinked from the document), what i did to succeed is create a virtual host at the root of my PC ( C/ ), there i have no problem setting url like this:

```
http://domain-local.com/profil/50bfbd859170a/home
```

but i'll have to do this on every url in the project . is there another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a rewrite rule ? I'm not sure to understand your project, but something like this may work :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-z]*)/([a-z0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$     $1/$2-$3-$4    [L]
```

It will redirect your new URLs to the old ones...